# add posts and make searchable

Tags: wordpress

I have created a wrodpress site. I would like to have a page where I can post recipes. The page should only show 5 recipes at a time but let the user navigate between all recepies.
Something like this:

```
Recipe 1
 Recipe 2
 Recipe 3
 Recipe 4
 Recipe 5
<Prev  2 3 4 5 .. Next>
```

I also want visitors to be able to search for a recipe. Not like the normal search that search the whole page but only recipe posts.

Any recommendations on plugins that can achieve this?

Comment: Use Google.  There's several recipe plugins to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great way to do this would be to use Custom Post Types. This tutorial explains almost exactly what you want to do, including the fact that it's based on recipes: http://wpmu.org/easy-guide-to-displaying-custom-post-types-in-your-wordpress-theme/

As far as a search limited to only that custom post type goes, you could modify or duplicate searchform.php like so without having to use a plugin at all:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" >
        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Enter keywords ..."/>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="recipes" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search Recipes" />
</form>
```

If you have trouble getting this to work, make sure the following is included at the top of search.php :

```
<?php
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = $query_split[1];
} // foreach

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
?>
```